# Openrowset from CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am trying to read from a CSV file located on shared folder on the network but getting error for the following code:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTbl
FROM OPENROWSET
('SQLNCLI11',
'ServerName = <username>;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
DefaultDir=\\sharedpath\DIR path\;
SELECT * FROM CSV_File.csv) as Test
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

When I remove the server line like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTbl
FROM OPENROWSET
('SQLNCLI11',
--'ServerName = <username>';Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
DefaultDir=\\sharedpath\DIR path\;
SELECT * FROM CSV_File.csv) as Test
```

I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid authorization specification".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. Authentication failed.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)".
```

What does that mean?  Does this error message indicate something wrong in my script or is access permission issue?  I was able to read from a table on the server suing the same openrowset connection when I no longer use the CSV driver.

I am not sure what to do in order to get this openrowset to read the CSV file. Any clue? Do you think it has to do with the server account does not have access to the account I am using does not have access to the shared folder?

Comment: First of all, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be closing the single-apostrophe in the connection string before the string is completed.

Comment: I am not following you. Where exactly?

Comment: After <UserName> and after TrustedConnection=yes;

Comment: No that is just a type here in the editor. I checked in SQL it looks fine

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong provider.  Your connection string is written for connecting to a server (sort of).  You should be using the bulk option for OPENROWSET per example E on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

It would look something like this, although you need to create a format file per the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx).

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.bcp',
    FORMATFILE = 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.xml'  
   ) AS t1;
```

Comment: I can't use the format file since I want this to be inside a stored procedure that will run every night to populate the temp table and populating the main table from the temp table after that .

Comment: If the file format is always the same, then making a format file is a one-off.  You just define it the first go-around.  If the format changes, then your problem gets significantly more complex.

Comment: It change every time and I can't predict the changes

Comment: Any idea of how to resolve this or at least how to auto create the fmt file?

Comment: No.  What you are suggesting is to dynamically figure out what your metadata is.  That is quite the requirement.  The only way I could possibly even handle that would be by importing all your data into a big column and then write T-SQL to parse.  That would not be my tool of choice, however.

Comment: I got it fixed:    SELECT *
INTO #TempTbl
from openrowset('MSDASQL','Driver= {Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; 
                   DefaultDir=\\server\folderpath\'
               ,'select * from file_name.csv') as Test